# variable size list of connection strings in cscfg

Tags: list, azure, schema, cscfg

I have an Azure Service and I'm using .cscfg files for my configurations.
When my service loads the .cscfg, it expects to have there at least 1 connection string.

The problem is, more connection strings may be added later to the cscfg file and I do not want to change my code in order to handle them too.

I couldn't find a way to write the cscfg in a way that it'll build a list of connection strings.
Do you know if this is possible? if not, what would you suggest I do? How would I process all the connection strings without changing the code every time that I add another connection string to the cscfg?

Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I couldn't find a way to write the cscfg in a way that it'll build a
>   list of connection strings. Do you know if this is possible?

Unlike `app/web.config` files where you have a dedicated `ConnectionStrings` element, it is `NOT` possible to do the same with a service config file. As far as settings are concerned, it is simple `name/value` pair.

> How would I process all the connection strings without changing the
>   code every time that I add another connection string to the cscfg?

Just thinking out loud, you could possibly save all the connection strings in a serialized JSON array and have just one key named something like `ConnectionStrings` and have your code parse this JSON array and create different connection strings based on the keys in this JSON array.